# Cast to string failed for value

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose, bluebird

I have this problem I'm tired  I can't solve this problem `Cast to string failed for value \"{}\" at path \"post\`

```
{
  "confirmation": "fail",
  "message": {
    "message": "Cast to string failed for value \"{}\" at path \"post\"",
    "name": "CastError",
    "stringValue": "\"{}\"",
    "kind": "string",
    "value": {

    },
    "path": "post"
  }
}
```

hope you will help me

**index.html**

```
    <h1>CreateComment</h1>
    <form action="/api/comment" method="post">
      <input type="text" name="post" placeholder="Post" /><br />
      <input type="text" name="text" placeholder="Text"><br />
      <input type="submit" value"Create" />
    </form>
```

**Comment.js**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose')

var CommentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  profile: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.Mixed, default: {}},
  post: {type: String, default:{}},
  text: {type: String, default: ''},
  timestamp: {type:Date, default:Date.now}
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('CommentSchema', CommentSchema);
```

**controllers.js**

```
var Comment = require('../models/Comment')
var promise = require('bluebird')

module.exports = {

  post: function(params, isRaw) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      Comment.create(params, function(err, comment) {
        if (err) {
          reject(err)
          return
        }
        console.log(comment)
        resolve(comment)
      })
    })
  }

}
```

**api.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var controllers = require('../controllers');


router.post('/:resource', function(req, res, next) {
  var resource = req.params.resource;
  var controller = controllers[resource];

  if (controller == null) {
    res.json({
      confirmation: 'fail',
      message: 'Invalid Resource'
    })

    return
  }

  controller.post(req.body, false)
    .then(function(result) {
      res.json({
        confirmation: 'success',
        result: result
      })
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
      res.json({
        confirmation: 'fail',
        message: err
      })
    })
})

module.exports = router;
```

this all of my codes

Comment: Can you do a little debugging first and come to us with an actual question? Maybe show what you've tried?

Comment: expecting type is `string` for which you got response as `object`.

Answer (score 5):

I think that {} is not a valid default for the 'post' member.

```
post: {type: String, default:{}},
```

Either the 'post' default value should be a string and you need to provide one, or an empty object, and then the type should not be "String".

Comment: Thanks dude you are true

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at my response in this other related question.
The same applies for 'reserved mongoose words' such as 'type' and 'value':

https://stackoverflow.com/a/72392997/9936281

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31870923)