# CastError: Cast to string failed for value

Tags: node.js, mongoose, nosql

I wanted to created a transaction module where after a successful transaction the users document(in this case user sends money to another user) will be updated as well.

a. in user.js(this is user model) besides name, pw, email (etc) I created this property which will hold the transaction related history of respective user. Please look at how I’ve used it:

```
transaction_history:[{
            transactionid:String,
            timestamp:String,
            type:String,
            balance:Number,
            status:String

        }]
```

b. when sender clicks send button in the form, a transaction document is created, & after this the user document(here the sender) should be updated along with transaction info.

```
//create transaction document, works fine
Transaction.create({transactionid:uniqid(),
                timestamp:moment().format(datemask),
                amount:balance,
                sender:sendfrom,
                receiver:sendto,
                status:"done"
}, function(err, tr){
    if(err) throw err;
    else {

        //I want sender document to update with transaction info
        User.findOne({email:sendfrom}, function(err, sendfrom){
            if(err) {console.log("error at sender side");}
            else 
            if(sendfrom!=null){
                // console.log("tr: "+tr); //fine
                sendfrom.balance-=balance;
                sendfrom.transaction_history.push({

                     transactionid:tr.transactionid, 


                    // timestamp:tr.timestamp,
                    // type:"debit",
                    // balance:tr.amount,
                    // status:tr.status 

                }
                );
                sendfrom.save();
                console.log("sender's current balance is: "+sendfrom.balance);


            };
            });
            }});
```

c. But then I get this:

```
events.js:163
  throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
  ^
CastError: Cast to string failed for value "{ transactionid: '1amhrummxjhnhv0w4' }" at path "transaction_history"
```

Why this error occurs?I want your suggestion please! Thank you

Comment: You're passing in a JSON string,`"{ transactionid: '1amhrummxjhnhv0w4' }` and not just the value `'1amhrummxjhnhv0w4'`

Answer (score 7):

You can't use the word 'type' as an object. Just rename to something else like 'something_type'.

Comment: you can, just do `type:{type:<your type>}` inside the schema

Answer (score 2):

Root of the problem is in the way I defined transaction_history property. This was supposed to be an array of objects syntactically[{}], but then I wrote its type to be String. So when I tried to insert a string as a value of ’type’, it throws error being unable to push string to ‘transaction_history’ object. To solve it, just need to remove type property. It’s my mistake to use a reserved word as a key in object.So I replaced 'type' by something else in model. that’s it!

Answer (score 2):

At my case:

```
CastError: Cast to String failed for value "[ 'whateverValue_1', 'whateverValue_2' ]" at path "name"
```

Issue was that I have in form html name same word...

I.e:

```
<input name = "name"> Name 
<input city = "name"> City
```

Looking for my mistake, I leave you other that could help for newbies as me:

words like `type`, `model`, never have to be in model Schema as main keywords!

Answer (score 1):

There is a workaround provided by Mongoose:

You **can** use the field "type" in the object as long as you define its type, as such:

```
transaction_history: [
  {
    transactionId: String,
    timestamp: String,
    type: { type: String },
    balance: Number,
    status: String
  }
]
```

source: https://www.typeerror.org/docs/mongoose/schematypes